# Goroutine analogues in other languages

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

Concurrency is really hard part of programming. Recent time goroutine is very popular. My question is - What kind of goroutine analogues exist in other languages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

goroutine are inspired by [CSP (Communicating sequential processes)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes), which is highly influential in the design of the [occam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam_(programming_language)) programming language, and also influenced the design of programming languages such as [Limbo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limbo_(programming_language)), [RaftLib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RaftLib), [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(programming_language)), and [Crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_(programming_language)).

Note that [goroutine are not without criticisms](http://www.jtolds.com/writing/2016/03/go-channels-are-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/).

It differs from the [Actor Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) in that:

- CSP processes are anonymous, while actors have identities.
- CSP message-passing fundamentally involves a rendezvous between the processes involved in sending and receiving the message. In contrast, message-passing in actor systems is fundamentally asynchronous
- CSP uses explicit channels for message passing, whereas actor systems transmit messages to named destination actors.